# Tensorflow2 - Use "tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset" with "tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array"

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, keras, time-series

I am trying to get TensorFlow to read +100 CSV files that ***don't*** fit in memory (+1GB size each). The files contain time series data (EEG signals), with the labels in the first column. From the TensorFlow documentation it seems like I should be able to use the *tf.data* API to load my data off-disk.

For the sake of simplicity and reproducibility, let's consider the following "*sample_data.csv*" dataset:

| Label | Feature 1 | Feature 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | 2 |
| Banana | 3 | 4 |
| Coconut | 5 | 6 |
| Durian | 7 | 8 |

I've tried using [tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset) to load the CSV files into *tf.data.Dataset* objects, and then [tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/timeseries_dataset_from_array) to process the data into sliding windows with overlap. For the dataset above, I would do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_data = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    'sample_data.csv',
    batch_size=1,
    column_names=['Label', 'Feature 1', 'Feature 2']
    label_name='Label',
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False
)
```

Which we can check works correctly by looking at the output from `list(input_data.as_numpy_iterator())`. We can then feed `input_data` to the next function:

```
my_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    input_data,
    targets=None,
    sequence_length=3,
    sequence_stride=2,
    sampling_rate=1,  
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=False
)
```

Which unfortunately **throws this error**:

> TypeError: dataset length is unknown.

I also tried using `my_dataset = input_data.window(3, shift=2)` (see the [tf.data.Dataset.window](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#window) documentation) and it didn't throw an error, but
it seems to be returning an **empty dataset**? See "*_VariantDataset shapes: (None,)*" in the output:

```
list(input_data.window(3, shift=2))

[344]:
[(OrderedDict([('Feature 1',
                <_VariantDataset shapes: (None,), types: tf.int32>),
               ('Feature 2',
                <_VariantDataset shapes: (None,), types: tf.int32>)]),
  <_VariantDataset shapes: (None,), types: tf.string>),
 (OrderedDict([('Feature 1',
                <_VariantDataset shapes: (None,), types: tf.int32>),
               ('Feature 2',
                <_VariantDataset shapes: (None,), types: tf.int32>)]),
  <_VariantDataset shapes: (None,), types: tf.string>),
 (OrderedDict([('Feature 1',
                <_VariantDataset shapes: (None,), types: tf.int32>),
               ('Feature 2',
                <_VariantDataset shapes: (None,), types: tf.int32>)]),
  <_VariantDataset shapes: (None,), types: tf.string>)]
```

If I load the "*sample_data.csv*" in memory using pandas and then feed the *timeseries_dataset_from_array* function a numpy array instead, it works correctly.

Any ideas on how to solve this? **What's the best method to input overlapping windows from off-memory time-series data into TensorFlow**?

Thank you!

Comment: I am trying this now. Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The code works but is slow and GPU is under utilized. There is extra column to prevent windows that contains two different files, which for many problems could be removed. There are 3 columns feature1, feature2, feature3. The code returns windows of feature1 and feature2 and single point from feature3 but that could be easily adjusted. It is to predict value of feature3 based on feature1 and feature2.

```
def pack_features_vector(features):
    features = tf.stack([tf.cast(x,tf.float32) for x in list(features.values())], axis=1)
    return features


def read_dataset(file_path, min_array, max_array, shuffle_enabled=False, batch_size = 512, window_size=50, for_forecast=False,make_sequences=True):
    
    if min_array is None or max_array is None:
        scaling_on = False
    else:
        scaling_on = True
    
    
    if scaling_on:
        # This is required for Normalization X-Min_X/(Max_X-Min_X) the first element is unique file id that we don't need to normalize as it
        # is use for filtering and removing sequences that have mixed file ids so we do not cross data from different units
        max_np = np.insert(max_array,0,1)
        min_np = np.insert(min_array,0,0)
        min_list = list(min_np)

        denominator_list = list(max_np-min_np) # Need list that will be used to divide element wise for Normalization
    
    # Shuffle files
    if shuffle_enabled:
        shuffle(file_path)
    
    # Read csv files (cannot use parallel as it would mix samples, we can shuffle
    building_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(file_pattern=file_path,
                                                        batch_size=1024,num_epochs=1, shuffle=False,
                                                        select_columns=['file_id','feature1','feature2','feature3'],
                                                        num_parallel_reads=1)
    
   
    building_dataset = building_dataset.map(pack_features_vector)
    building_dataset = building_dataset.flat_map(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x))

    if scaling_on:
        building_dataset = building_dataset.map(lambda x: (x-min_list)/denominator_list)#/(np.array[1,105,1005,10005]-np.array[0,100,1000,10000]))
     
    # Make overlapping sequences and filter some that go over different files
    if make_sequences:
        building_dataset = building_dataset.window(window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
        building_dataset = building_dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size))

        building_dataset = building_dataset.filter(lambda window: tf.reduce_sum(window[:-1,0]-window[1:,0])==0) # Check if windows is for single file_id (no crossing allowed) (column 0)

        
        if not for_forecast:
            building_dataset = building_dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:,1:-1], window[-((window_size)//2),-1]))   #building_dataset = building_dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:,:-1], window[-1:,-1]))
        else:
            building_dataset = building_dataset.map(lambda window: window[:,1:-1])
    else:
        building_dataset = building_dataset.map(lambda x: x[1:])

    if shuffle_enabled:
        building_dataset = building_dataset.shuffle(1000)
    
    building_dataset = building_dataset.batch(batch_size)
    
    building_dataset = building_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    
    return building_dataset
```